# In Swift, How to print NSMutableArray in textView

Tags: swift

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let userDefaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let itemListFromUserDefaults:NSMutableArray? = userDefaults.objectForKey("itemList") as? NSMutableArray
    if((itemListFromUserDefaults) != nil){
        toDoItems = itemListFromUserDefaults!
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    print("toDoItems")
    print(toDoItems)
}
```

In Swift, I used CoreData to save groceries list, now I want to print toDoItems in a textView, How to do it

Answer (score 0):

Create an NSString out of the NSArray using map, and then assign that string to the textView's text property.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, try this:

```
textView.text = arr.joinWithSeparator(",")
```